# Mac daemon not able to run bash script

Tags: terminal, command-line, permission, launchd, plist

Originally [asked on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65677362/10200417), but it may be more suited for here. Wherever it’s answered first, I’ll be sure to update the counterpart question with the same answer.

I've already checked [this similar question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/263307/i-cant-get-my-launch-daemon-to-run-my-shell-script).

> **OS** MacOS 10.15.17 (Catalina)

I want to create a script that uses [iperf](https://iperf.fr) to launch a client that measures my connection speed every several seconds for an extended period. I’ve created a daemon file and put it in `~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.myself.iperfclient.plist`.

#### com.myself.iperfclient.plist

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>Label</key>
        <string>com.myself.iperfclient</string>
        
        <key>ProgramArguments</key>
        <array>
            <string>/Users/myself/Documents/bin/iperf/netspeed</string>
        </array>

        <key>StartInterval</key>
        <integer>20</integer>  <!-- in seconds -->

        <key>Disabled</key>
        <false/>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

#### netspeed

```bsh
#!/bin/bash


# see https://stackoverflow.com/a/246128/10200417
script_dir="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" >/dev/null 2>&1 && pwd )"
script_name=`basename $0`
# echo "called script $script_name from $script_dir"

iperf_server=127.0.0.1
iperf_port=54321

# launch iperf client, log results to ./logs/client.log
iperf \
    -c $iperf_server \
    -p $iperf_port \
    --logfile $script_dir/logs/client.log
```

The `netspeed` file is executable for anyone:

```
$ ls -l netspeed
  -rwxr-xr-x@ 1 myself  staff  379 Jan 11 21:36 netspeed
```

When I try to add the new daemon, with `launchctl load ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.myself.iperfclient.plist`, this is the error message I get in the Console:

```
Sandbox: bash(50654) System Policy: deny(1) file-read-data /Users/myself/Documents/bin/iperf/netspeed
```

If in the `.plist` descriptor for the daemon I add `<string>open</string>` as the first item in `ProgramArguments`, there’s no error. However, I don’t want to run the script this way because it launches a new Terminal window every time, which is extremely annoying.

### My question

How do I allow my daemon process to execute `netspeed`?

### P.S.

The launchctl status code is **126**.

```
$ launchctl list | grep myself
-   126 com.myself.iperfclient
```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else struggling with fdautil (as I was), you need to set the command from the command line before it will work from launchcontrol.

For example:

```
sudo /usr/local/bin/fdautil set daemon LABEL /bin/bash /full/path/to/your/script.sh
```

LABEL can be whatever you like - it's just a way to refer to your script if you want to remove it from fdautil later.

Once you have done this, your LaunchAgents plist file should look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.yourdomain.LABEL</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/local/bin/fdautil</string>
        <string>exec</string>
        <string>/bin/bash</string>
        <string>/full/path/to/your/script.sh</string>
    </array>
    <integer>60</integer>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 1):

Alright, here’s what I ended up doing, which does work and doesn’t require any other installations. I tried [the answer from Gilby](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/411030/320992), but wasn’t able to get **fdautil** to work after downloading and installing it via the LaunchControl trial version.

If it had worked, it seems it would have done so by granting LaunchControl’s **fdautil** utility full disk access, which would then use those permissions somehow to execute my `netspeed` script (without passing those permissions to `/bin/bash`?).

### Method 1: AppleScript wrapper

I created `Users/myself/Documents/bin/iperf/netspeed.scpt`, which has the following:

```
do shell script "/Users/myself/Documents/bin/iperf/netspeed"
```

I then updated the **ProgramArguments** entry in the launchd plist to:

```xml
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
    <string>/usr/bin/osascript</string>
    <string>/Users/myself/Documents/bin/iperf/netspeed.scpt</string>
</array>
```

Finally, in `System Preferences > Security and Privacy > Files and Folders` I was able to grant access for `Users/myself/Documents` to `/usr/bin/osascript`, and successfully launch the daemon.

### Method 2: Put script in location with less security

As @user3439894 pointed out, since the main reason it was difficult to execute `netspeed` in the first place was that I had it in `~myself/Documents.../`, which has elevated permissions requirements, I can also just put it in a location with less security.

I followed the suggestion to try `/Users/Shared/.../netspeed` and it indeed worked with my original script and plist contents! To be clear, the **ProgramArguments** would now be:

```xml
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
    <string>/Users/Shared/.../netspeed</string>
</array>
```

Comment: If you put the _executable_ in `/Users/Shared` or in a user created _folder_ in the _root_ of your _home folder_ you should have to go through all this rigmarole.

Comment: @user3439894 Ah, that may be the case as well; I’ve not tried it yet.

Comment: @user3439894 I tested to confirm your suggestion works, and updated the answer accordingly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The program you want to run is bash, so the program arguments should be:

```
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/bin/bash</string>
        <string>/Users/myself/Documents/bin/iperf/netspeed</string>
    </array>
```

But I suspect that you may still get sandbox errors.  To avoid this use the fdautil command which is part of [Launch Control](https://soma-zone.com/LaunchControl/).  Then you use:

```
<key>ProgramArguments</key>
<array>
    <string>/usr/local/bin/fdautil</string>
    <string>exec</string>
    <string>/bin/bash</string>
    <string>/Users/myself/Documents/bin/iperf/netspeed</string>
</array>
```

This is the mechanism I have used to launch a python script (with the obvious difference).

This answer maybe incomplete, but see how you go.

Comment: It should be possible to execute a bash script directly from launchd (well, actually it *is* possible), no need to pass it as an argument to bash.

Comment: Glad to know that.  On the few occasions I have done this specifying the shell (or whatever) avoids some confusion - particularly between of versions of python! Will be interested to see if the fdautil method helps the owengall.  I will amend my answer when we hear from him.

Comment: Would I need to purchase launch control to run fdautil? I tried downloading the trial, then installing `/usr/local/bin/fdautil` as directed in **Help**, but if I try to run `fdautil exec <my_script>` it says “You don't have permission to run this command via fdautil”. fdautil is already given full disk access.

Comment: Also, I looked for `/Library/Preferences/com.soma-zone.LaunchControl.fdautil.plist`, which is where **fdautil** puts the script it allows to run, but that plist file doesn’t exist.